# VS 2017 Color Theme Editor - How to Change Intellisense Autocomplete Background Color

Tags: visual-studio, ide, vs-color-theme-editor

I've imported a transparent theme using Color Theme Editor and I'm trying to change the background color of the autocomplete box. Currently (shown below) it's transparent and making it hard to read with text on the below lines.

I've tried a number of elements but can't find the right one. Google yields nothing.

How can I change the autocomplete / intellisense autocomplete box background color?

[image: Autocomplete box]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the treeview background to be solid

[image]