# Change Intellisense Quick Info parameter Background/Foreground colors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have just installed a theme extension for visual studio 2017.
My new theme looks fine but there is one problem, the intellisense quick info box background is white and info text is unreadable (see the picture). How can I change the background color of quick info panel? 
[image: this is how it looks]

Comment: It would help other users if you mentioned the name of the theme extensions. If it is Color Theme Editor then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54660317/5209435) might help.

Comment: here is the link, its easy to install and use

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.VisualStudio2017ColorThemeEditor

Comment: See the link on my original comment, otherwise the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31574915/overriding-intellisense-colors-in-visual-studio-2015) should sort you out.